# n+1 balls put into n bins. Double count?

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

Question:
n+1 balls are put into n bins. What is the probability that all of the bins are not empty (contain 1 ball at least)?

What I did:

Choose n balls from the n+1 ${n+1 \choose n}$, order them in the bins (n!), choose one bin to put the remaining ball in (n). That sums up to: ${n+1 \choose n}n!n$. 
I think there's a double count somewhere, but it all seems logical to me...  Anyone can please explain me what I have counted twice?  ($|\Omega|$ - is the number of ways to put the balls in the bins) $|\Omega| = n^{n+1}$  of course. So the probability is ${{n+1 \choose n}n!n} \over {n^{n+1}}$

Comment: What does "full" mean? That all bins contain at least one ball?

Comment: 1. ${n+1\choose n } n!n$ is not a probability. 2. What is $\Omega$?  You need to explain your notation here for us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

How many ways ate there to put $n+1$ balls into $n$ bins? How many ways are there such that every bin has at least one ball?

Answer (score 2):

Let us make a probability model of the situation. We have $n+1$ labelled balls, and $n$ bins. We toss the balls one at a time towards the bins. Assume that a ball is rqually likely to land in any of the bins, and that the results of the $n+1$ tosses are independent.

The experiment has $n^{n+1}$ equally likely outcomes.

We now count the "favourable" outcomes, the ones in which no bin is empty.

The two balls that will end up t0gether can be chosen in $\dbinom{n+1}{2}$ ways. Glue these two balls together. We now have $n$ "balls". They can be arranged among the $n$ bins, one "ball" to each bin, in $n!$ ways.

Thus the number of favourables is $\dbinom{n+1}{2}n!$.

**Remark:** You have almost the same answer, just off by a factor of $2$. At a certain stage, you chose $n$ balls to be arranged in the bins, so implicitly you chose $1$ ball to be temporarily left behind. Then you chose where to place that ball.

Imagine two balls, A and B. Included in your count is A being left behind, and the remaining balls being arranged in alphabetical order, so with B in the first bin. And then A being placed also in the first bin.

You have also counted B being left behind, the others arranged in order, and then B being placed to join A in the first bin.

But these give the same **function** from the set of balls to the set of bins.

Comment: Yeah, That's the solution that was written in the book and I do understand it, I just don't understand what was wrong in my trail of thought (where did I "double count" something in the solution I offered...) Thanks anyway, though

Comment: I added a lengthy remark about where the double-counting is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, now I've understood the mistake! Although it's more of a philosophical question - but how would you suggest avoiding these mistakes again? I feel like I'm just using intuition in these kind of questions and most of the time it's correct (but not always..)

Comment: Just do a lot of problems, and make most common mistakes a few times. Then one gets sensitized. One can also do a hand count of a few small cases, as a check.

Comment: @Guest86:  What is important is the probability model, not whether balls are distinguishable. If we toss $5$ distinguishable coins, the probability of exactly $2$ heads is exactly the same as if we toss $5$ indistinguishable coins. The Stars and Bars approach assumes that all ordered $n$-tuples $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ such that $x_1+\cdots+x_n=n+1$ are equally likely. If we toss balls into bins at random, it will not be true that all $n$-tuples are equally likely.  Your analysis of the balls tossed model at the end is well done.

Answer (score 1):

Your double count was here: choose $n$ balls from $n+1$ and than place the remaining one. What difference is when:

I choose balls 1..5 and place them in order and ball 6 give to the same basket as ball 5.

I choose balls 1..4 and 6, place them in order and ball 5 place to the same basket as ball 6.